# JOIN using a 'LIKE' on an XML Node?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've got a view that joins tables using a match on an xml node, like this example:

```
....CROSS APPLY xmlData.Nodes('/element/subElement')....
```

The problem is we now have elements called 'element2' and 'element3' which don't get picked up.  Is there a way to include these, almost using a LIKE on the nodes to pick these up as well?

Something along these lines:

```
....CROSS APPLY xmlData.Nodes('/element%/subElement')....
```

or is it a case of adding these extra nodes into the view manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an XQuery expression

```
CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/*/subElement')
```

**Update**

If you need to be more specific you can use

```
CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/*[substring(local-name(),1,7)="element"]/subElement')
```

in theroy `starts-with` would be better than `substring` but it does not work in SQL-server-2005 and I can't test with SQL-server-2008

Comment: But would that return everything, regardless of what the 'element' was called? eg. it'd pick up '/apple/subElement'?

Comment: @w69rdy: Yes, it will. It's equivalent to `.nodes('//subElement')`

Comment: @w69rdy Yes - I realized that and was testing some other solutions to match more specifically. My first attempt using `starts-with` is not supported in SQL 2005 which I am testing with so I settled on `contains`. See my edit.

Comment: @w69rdy - I switched `contains` to `substring` since it is even more specific and will not match cases like `/another-element/subElement`

Comment: You beauty! Thanks a lot, not worked with queries using xml much before and have been banging my head on the table trying to figure out how to do this!